# Fixing Undefined index: in php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a login using php. I want to have a remember me cookie set up so that the user does not need to login each time they visit the site.

When I run my code I get the following errors but don't know why

Undefined index: remember_me

Undefined index: username

Here is my php code

```html
<?php

$year = time() + 31536000;
setcookie('rememberme', $_POST['username'], $year);

if($_POST['remember_me']) {
setcookie('rememberme', $_POST['username'], $year);
}
elseif(!$_POST['remember_me']) {
  if(isset($_COOKIE['rememberme'])) {
    $past = time() - 100;
    setcookie(remember_me, gone, $past);
  }
}
```

here is my html

```html
    <input class="userform" id="username" name="username" required="required" type="text" size="10" placeholder="Username"value="<?php
echo $_COOKIE['remember_me']; ?>"/>
</div>

  <input class="userform" id="password" name="password" required="required" type="password" size="10" placeholder="Password" />  
  </div>

  <br>
<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me">
        Remember me 

<br>
<br>

                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
        </div>
```

This is not a duplicate

Comment: use isset() function to check the variables

Comment: what value you got in method attribute in your form?

Comment: tried that but nothing appears